# React: avoid controlled component boilerplate

Tags: reactjs

So I'm just asking out of curiosity,

Anyone found a clever way to handle 2-way data binding in controlled components (input, select, ...) without having to write all of the following:

```
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {value: 'Hello!'};
  },
  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  },
  render: function() {
    var value = this.state.value;
    return <input type="text" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} />;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to read "Two-Way Binding Helpers" section of the documentation:
http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html

There is this `LinkedStateMixin`:

```
var NoLink = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {message: 'Hello!'};
  },
  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({message: event.target.value});
  },
  render: function() {
    var message = this.state.message;
    return <input type="text" value={message} onChange={this.handleChange} />;
  }
});


var WithLink = React.createClass({
  mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {message: 'Hello!'};
  },
  render: function() {
    return <input type="text" valueLink={this.linkState('message')} />;
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks like there's no support for Mixin and ES6 classes in React >= 0.13. So if you want to use this you'll have to write your components in the old `React.createClass()` way. https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#mixins

Comment: Just informing that teh `LinkedStateMixin` has become deprecated. We should find a better solution. Thanks for the inspiration though

Answer (score 5):

A trick that's worth knowing - since the `onChange` event bubbles up, you can wrap form inputs in a container and register the `onChange` on that instead - `<form>` is perfect for this.

Then you can write a generic `onChange` handler which pulls data from the event's `target` - you will need to add some identifying info to the field, which is what the `name` attribute is for anyway.

Here's a [Gist with an example implementation](https://gist.github.com/insin/082c0d88f6290a0ea4c7) and a [live demo](http://bl.ocks.org/insin/raw/082c0d88f6290a0ea4c7/) of it in action - form input state is displayed below the form.

Comment: I like the approach even more then the suggested mixin, because I already have some kind of a generic onChange. So thanks!